# Fresh Qt installation does not run Qt projects, including many of Qt Example projects, says “shader program not linked”

Tags: qt, opengl, shader, pyqt5

Yesterday I installed Qt 5.4 on my windows 7 PC. But I can not build and run any Qt project including those given in Examples section on the Welcome page of Qt Creator 3.3 except for a few. Also, I can’t run any qml file either using this command from cmd: “qmlscene myqmlfile.qml”

Please note that I have added this path to my environment variables:

> C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\bin

and Qt installation directory is

> C:\Qt

The error message I get in the output window in Qt creator, and in console when running a qml file from cmd, is as follows:

```
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( qt_Matrix ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed:
""
```

Previously, I used PyQt5, and ran qml files using the command

> qmlscene myqmlfile.qml

without any problem. Then installed Qt Creator 3.3 to run Qt projects, but failed (got some error saying problem in qmake). Finally I uninstalled PyQt5 and Qt Creator 3.3, downloaded Qt 5.4 and installed it, but still could not run Qt projects.
I found in some website, that I need open GL 2.0 to run Qt projects in Qt 5.4. How do I make sure that I have openGL 2.0? (I checked with GPU-Z and it shows my shader model 2.0 and I don’t know if it has anything to do with OpenGL :( )

Please help me correct whatever is wrong with my Qt installation. This is freaking annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have Intel Graphics Driver installed from **Intel**. Microsoft's default drivers do not include OpenGL support.

Comment: Thanks. After installing Intel Graphics driver, "shader program is not linked" error is gone!